# how i can disable the right menu on one controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

recently i used this library to make slide menu , what i found that this library give me slide from right and left

https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

what if i want to disable the right menu

or if i want to show it in only one controller

i try to disable it by doing this

i delete the rightViewController but the action still work and show me black screen

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController
    let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController

    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)


    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:mvc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)
```

Comment: The library requires you to call openLeft and openRight. If you don't call openRight, how can it be displaying?

Comment: i edit my questions , i was meant to delete the right menu ,

Answer (score 1):

i fix it by edit 1 line in UIViewController.swift file

```
func setNavigationBarItem() {
    //self.addLeftBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "ic_notifications_black_24dp")!)
    self.addRightBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "ic_menu_black_24dp")!)
    self.slideMenuController()?.removeLeftGestures()
    self.slideMenuController()?.removeRightGestures()
    self.slideMenuController()?.addLeftGestures()
    self.slideMenuController()?.addRightGestures()
}
```

^_^

Answer (score 0):

Just delete these two methods from your code and that will do the trick

`self.slideMenuController()?.openRight()
self.slideMenuController()?.closeRight()`

Its clearly mentioned in the github documentation.

Hope this helps you...